# How to make that query with Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have 2 django models:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    msg = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Thread(models.Model):
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message)
```

Is it possible to make one query via Django ORM equivalent to SQL:

```
SELECT   Message.msg, Message.date
FROM     Message, Thread
WHERE    Message.id IN Thread.messages
AND      Thread.id IN (1,2,3)
ORDER BY Message.date
LIMIT    10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
messages = Message.objects.filter(thread__id__in=[1,2,3]).order_by('date')[:10]
```

using the [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) and [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) queryset methods, [querying across a relationship in reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), and [slicing to limit the results](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)